# Prevent Script from Running Twice in async operation (true/false)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, telegram

Messing with the telegram api in javascript, my code is set-up like so:

```
(async () => {

    var greeting = false;

    await telegramListener(
        async (message) => {

        const regex = new RegExp(foo*);
        
        if (regex.test(message) && greeting !== true) {
            var greeting = true;
            console.log('greeting');
        }
    }
}
```

This does not work though. `greeting` is always false on the start of each new message.

What is the trick in order to make my conditional `if` statement only run once in the above code?

Comment: `var greeting = true;` creates a new variable. Since it's hoisted, you never use the outer `var greeting = false;`.

Comment: Oh wow. That easy huh. Took off the `var` and just did `greeting = true;` and it seems to be working properly. Thank you!